# Blazor server side openid signout issue

Tags: iis, server, blazor, openid, openiddict

I am devlopping a web site with Blazor Server Side. I'm using Openiddict for openid authentication. When i make a signout :

```
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

i have an error :

```
2022-04-06T15:32:40.8217702+02:00 [ERR] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware) An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.ThrowIfReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.set_Item(String key, StringValues value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.set_ContentType(StringValues value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_ContentType(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
2022-04-06T15:32:40.8425233+02:00 [WRN] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware) The response has already started, the error handler will not be executed.
2022-04-06T15:32:40.8468997+02:00 [ERR] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer) Connection ID ""18086456104325218332"", Request ID ""4000001d-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
```

Precision: the website is hosted on iis and i don't have error in debug with kestrel...

Could you help me?

Comment: It seems this is a general problem exists in blazor. The best way would be to look into the official Blazor Templates with authentication (Create New Project => Blazor App => Create => Change Authentication). If you for some reason must work with HttpContext, HttpContext should not be used in a Blazor server-side application.. A possible workaround is to create Login/Logout razor pages. The razor pages can access the HttpContext, sign in and then redirect to your actual home page. https://www.blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/36

Comment: I'm ok with you about blazor and httpContext and so the login and logout redirection are already done in a razor page ActionIdp.cshtml in the cs i have a method public async Task OnGetAsync(string action, string returnUrl) and if the action is logout i do  await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(...)